# SpannableString looses spans when used multiple times

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, spannablestring

This is the code that I have.

```kotlin
val s = SpannableString("hello")
s.setSpan(StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, s.length, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
textView.text = TextUtils.concat(s, s)
```

The text shown in textView is: **hello**hello

Why aren't both "hello" in bold?

**Edit:** I am actually trying to concatenate some `SpannableString`s with some normal `String`s, something like `TextUtils.concat("A", s, "B", s, "C")` (the result of which I expect to be A**hello**B**hello**C). Replacing `SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE` with `SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE` solves the "**hello**hello" problem but not this one.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils#concat(java.lang.CharSequence...):

> If there are paragraph spans in the source CharSequences that satisfy paragraph boundary requirements in the sources but would no longer satisfy them in the concatenated CharSequence, they may get extended in the resulting CharSequence or not retained.

While this isn't super clear (at least to me) I infer that paragraph boundaries are extended if they should be extended. They should be extended if they are INCLUSIVE boundaries meaning if you insert at the beginning you should use `Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE` or `Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE`, if you append at the end, you should use `Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE` or `Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE`.

So use `Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE` instead of `Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE` (I tested it and it works).

With SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE:

[image]

With SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE:

[image]

After some digging I found TextUtils is using SpannableStringBuilder.append which is using SpannableStringBuilder.replace (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder#replace(int,%20int,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int)) under the hood and the replace is considered an insert at the end. With SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE it would not expand the formatting while it would with SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE:

> If the source contains a span with Spanned#SPAN_PARAGRAPH flag, and it does not satisfy the paragraph boundary constraint, it is not retained.

I also checked the resulting span and printed the start/end of the StyleSpan. The first line with SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE the last line with SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE:

```
01-14 12:44:11.218  5017  5017 E test    : span start/end: 0/5
01-14 12:44:22.575  5079  5079 E test    : span start/end: 0/10
```

Comment: `Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE` doesn't seem to work for me. Did you try it on the same code that is in the question?

Comment: @ArpitShukla yes exactly that code, I use an EditText though, not a TextView. See my screenshots.

Comment: But `Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE` seems to continue the span till the end. I tried `TextUtils.concat(s, s, "ok")` and it displayed **hellohellook**, all in bold which isn't desired.

Comment: In your question you want **hellohello** as a result which is exactly what `Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE` does. I'm not sure what the second example with TextUtils.concat(s, s, "ok") has to to with the original question.

Comment: Edited the question with the real requirements.

Answer (score 1):

If you append text to a `Spannable` it doesn't matter whether that text is just plain text or another `Spannable`. Spans in the original texts will either expand or not depending on the span's flags (`Spannable.SPAN_xyz_INCLUSIVE` vs `Spannable.SPAN_xyz_EXCLUSIVE`). That's why the bold formatting will either expand to the whole string with `TextUtils.concat("A", s, "B", s, "C")` (using `Spannable.SPAN_xyz_INCLUSIVE`) or not expand at all (using `Spannable.SPAN_xyz_EXCLUSIVE`).

Your attempt to append an already formatted `Spannable` won't work because a span can be used just once.

That's why this:

```
    val s = SpannableStringBuilder("hellohello")
    val span = StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD)
    s.setSpan(span, 0, 5, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
    s.setSpan(span, 5, 10, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
```

will result in hello**hello**, while this:

```
    val s = SpannableStringBuilder("hellohello")
    val span1 = StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD)
    val span2 = StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD)
    s.setSpan(span1, 0, 5, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
    s.setSpan(span2, 5, 10, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
```

will result in **hellohello**

This answers your question:

> Why aren't both "hello" in bold?

Unfortunately your question isn't very specific on what you're actually trying to achieve. If it's simply to have a `Spannable` with A**hello**B**hello**C, then you now know how. If your goal is to have a generic solution that allows to append arbitrary `Spannable` with arbitrary spans and keep those spans (`CharacterStyle` and `ParagraphStyle`) then you'll have to find a way to clone arbitrary `Spanned` texts with arbitrary spans (note if `s` is a `SpannableStringBuilder` then `s.subSequence(0, s.length)` copies spans but doesn't clone them). So here's how I'd do it:

```
private fun Spannable.clone(): Spannable {
    val clone = SpannableStringBuilder(toString())
    for (span in getSpans(0, length, Any::class.java)) {
        if (span is CharacterStyle || span is ParagraphStyle) {
            val st = getSpanStart(span).coerceAtLeast(0)
            val en = getSpanEnd(span).coerceAtMost(length)
            val fl = getSpanFlags(span)
            val clonedSpan = cloneSpan(span)
            clone.setSpan(clonedSpan, st, en, fl)
        }
    }
    return clone
}

private fun cloneSpan(span: Any): Any {
    return when (span) {
        is StyleSpan -> StyleSpan(span.style)
        // more clone code to be written...
        else -> span
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
val s  = SpannableString("hello")
s.setSpan(StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, s.length, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
textView.text = TextUtils.concat(s, " not bold ", s.clone())
```

Comment: Thanks for both of your answers. Probably you are right that `a span can be used just once`

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating a helper property to make strings bold.

```kotlin
val String.bold: CharSequence
    get() = buildSpannedString {
        append(this@bold, StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
    }
```

I still can't re-use `Spannable`s but probably it's because they can't be re-used (as @Emanuel suggested). But with this new property, the calling code looks pretty clean.

```kotlin
TextUtils.concat("A", "hello".bold, "B", "hello".bold, "C")
```

prints A**hello**B**hello**C